# BasicBlockList insertion error

Tags: llvm

```c
Function* NF= Function::Create(F->getFunctionType(), F->getLinkage());
BasicBlockListType& BList= NF->getBasicBlockList();
for(std::set<BasicBlock*>::iterator xit=BBsetArray[0].begin(); xit!=BBsetArray[0].end();xit++)
  {
    BList.push_back((*xit));
  }
```

for this code to insert basic blocks into the function basic block list I got the following error

```sh
opt: /home/rasha/llvm2/llvm/lib/IR/SymbolTableListTraitsImpl.h:68: void 
llvm::SymbolTableListTraits<llvm::BasicBlock,    
llvm::Function>::addNodeToList(ValueSubClass *) [ValueSubClass = llvm::BasicBlock, 
ItemParentClass = llvm::Function]: Assertion `V->getParent() == 0 && "Value already in 
a container!!"' failed.
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message seems pretty straightforward: the basic blocks you're trying to insert to the function are already contained in another function.

To solve this you can first call `removeFromParent()` on those blocks, but an altogether better way is not to move those basic blocks, but to clone them into a new function - this way also leaves the original function unchanged. To do this, take a look at the [CloneFunction()](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/namespacellvm.html#aabb040f50a7e75ad8d58bfc5d95636a4) function in "llvm/Transforms/Utils/Cloning.h".

Comment: I think 'removeFromParent' solves the error , I need to remove a group of basicblocks totally from the function with the edges related to that group inserted into the 'BasicBlockList' but the problem now is that the newfunction contains all basicblocks, although some of them are not in the extracted group